# Parse certain XML tags sequentially using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am trying to parse an XML file in a sequential manner, considering only XML-tags which are of interest. A sample XML file is shown below (stored as *file.xml*). I am only interested in certain XML-tags of known paths, as shown in the Python code snippet below (e.g. *header/para/paratext*, *body/section/intro/text*). Different XML files might have a different order of tags, so I do not want to prescribe in which order my known XML-tags will occur. Any suggestions how to do this in an efficient way without having to loop through the whole XML file?

**XML file**

```
<data>
  <header>
    <para>
      <paratext>0 - extract this</paratext>
    </para>
  </header>
  <body>
    <section>
      <intro>
        <text>1 - extract this</text>
      </intro>
      <para>
        <paratext>2 - extract this</paratext>
      </para>
      <items>
        <paratext>do not extract this</paratext>
        <part>
          <para>
            <paratext>3 - extract this</paratext>
          </para>
        </part>
      </items>
    </section>
    <section>
      <text>do not extract this</text>
      <intro>
        <text>4 - extract this</text>
      </intro>
      <para>
        <paratext>5 - extract this</paratext>
      </para>
      <para>
        <paratext>6 - extract this</paratext>
      </para>
    </section>
  </body>
</data>
```

**Desired output**: `['0 - extract this', '1 - extract this', '2 - extract this', '3 - extract this', '4 - extract this', '5 - extract this', '6 - extract this']`

**Sample Python script**:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

### Paths I would like to extract (but sequentially)
[i.text for i in root.findall('header/para/paratext')]
# ['0 - extract this']
[i.text for i in root.findall('body/section/intro/text')]
# ['1 - extract this', '4 - extract this']
[i.text for i in root.findall('body/section/para/paratext')]
# ['2 - extract this', '5 - extract this', '6 - extract this']
[i.text for i in root.findall('body/section/items/part/para/paratext')]
# ['3 - extract this']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to use the [union operator ("`|`") in XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#node-sets). That will select the desired elements in document order.

Unfortunately, ElementTree has [limited XPath support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support).

If you can use lxml, it has [much better XPath support](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html).

Example...

**Python**

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("file.xml")

print([i.text for i in tree.xpath('header/para/paratext|'
                                  'body/section/intro/text|'
                                  'body/section/para/paratext|'
                                  'body/section/items/part/para/paratext')])
```

**Printed Output**

```
['0 - extract this', '1 - extract this', '2 - extract this', '3 - extract this', '4 - extract this', '5 - extract this', '6 - extract this']
```